# Extract value from xml using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I've got this XML response from my api call:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<PPRESULTS s="DEV12" lst="8/10/2018 10:27:06 AM">
    <Results success="1" api="0" rolename="user" toolbarcode="standard" version="7.0">
        <usercontext status=" " managedbilling="False" managedmf="False" masteroffice="False" msooffice="False">xxxxxLGLQs+mbLDJ3X/zNwxdeehwhEathbBoHMVgLGnbNt7X8NcI8Y7KXwO+oOrRlnWscVxoUyo/E6WUPMkPWP8aSOW9ofwFL3b6mtFDR/GLLoJIFbduGD8civ9xF/KNyd8ceXmBc6/wi3wtyvrExjkEqbHwNL6aW60FrioUZo9eW4Z2BVkT3Xaqk4He+fx1ibp8XgEGklWKa7FoA7JEvtqcgLw==</usercontext>
    </Results>
</PPRESULTS>
```

And using XPATH I'd like to extract this text:

```
xxxxxLGLQs+mbLDJ3X/zNwxdeehwhEathbBoHMVgLGnbNt7X8NcI8Y7KXwO+oOrRlnWscVxoUyo/E6WUPMkPWP8aSOW9ofwFL3b6mtFDR/GLLoJIFbduGD8civ9xF/KNyd8ceXmBc6/wi3wtyvrExjkEqbHwNL6aW60FrioUZo9eW4Z2BVkT3Xaqk4He+fx1ibp8XgEGklWKa7FoA7JEvtqcgLw==
```

I've got this xpath `PPRESULTS/Results[1]/usercontext[1]` but it extracts everything within `<usercontext </usercontext>` How do I extract only that text? Keep in mind, that text is always changing it is a token.

Comment: This is unclear.  The text you want to extract ***is*** "everything within `<usercontext></usercontext>`".  Please show the text that your XPath expression _actually_ extracted.

Comment: @JimGarrison that is exactly what I would to write.Totally unclear.

Comment: Are you looking for the `text()` function? (as in `//usercontext//text()`)

Comment: This is what my xpath extracted `<usercontext status=" " managedbilling="False" managedmf="False" masteroffice="False" msooffice="False">xxxxxLGLQs+mbLDJ3X/zNwxdeehwhEathbBoHMVgLGnbNt7X8NcI8Y7KXwO+oOrRlnWscVxoUyo/E6WUPMkPWP8aSOW9ofwFL3b6mtFDR/GLLoJIFbduGD8civ9xF/KNyd8ceXmBc6/wi3wtyvrExjkEqbHwNL6aW60FrioUZo9eW4Z2BVkT3Xaqk4He+fx1ibp8XgEGklWKa7FoA7JEvtqcgLw==</usercontext>` @JimGarrison for clarity you're asking.

Comment: What are you using to evaluate the XPath? Are you programming in a language such as Java or Perl?  Did you try `PPRESULTS/Results[1]/usercontext[1]/text()`?

Comment: I am using a performance testing tool called neoload, my login call return the response above and using the tool's xpath extractor. I'm also testing the same xpath in https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: text() works, but the extractor the testing tool is using doesn't recognize text(). Any other way to extract the text?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript in the browser, you could do

```
document.evaluate('//usercontext//text()', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().textContent
```

(but check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript for more details).

If you're using Python, you could do:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.parse(open('foo.xml', 'rb'))
>>> print doc.xpath('//usercontext//text()')
['xxxxxLGLQs+mbLDJ3X/zNwxdeehwhEathbBoHMVgLGnbNt7X8NcI8Y7KXwO+oOrRlnWscVxoUyo/E6WUPMkPWP8aSOW9ofwFL3b6mtFDR/GLLoJIFbduGD8civ9xF/KNyd8ceXmBc6/wi3wtyvrExjkEqbHwNL6aW60FrioUZo9eW4Z2BVkT3Xaqk4He+fx1ibp8XgEGklWKa7FoA7JEvtqcgLw==']
```

in any case you'll need to use the `text()` function to get at the node's textual content.